# Access Response Object in a class ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, class, cookies, httpresponse

I have a function that checks if a cookie (by name) exists or not:

```
Private Function cookieExists(ByVal cName As String) As Boolean
    For Each c As HttpCookie In Response.Cookies
        If c.Name = cName Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

I have a class that handles cookies in an application-specific manner, and I want to consolidate all the cookie-related functions to this class.  However, I cannot use this code if I simply move it from the aspx page (where it currently resides) to the aforementioned class because I get the error: `'Name' Response is not declared.`  I modified the class to allow the passing of a reference to the **`Response`** object:

```
Public Function cookieExists(ByVal cName As String, ByRef Response As HttpResponse) As Boolean
    For Each c As HttpCookie In Response.Cookies
        If c.Name = cName Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

My question is: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: What is wrong with passing the Request and Response objects as parameters to the function?

Comment: @palswim if you want `function myFunc(response As System.Web.HttpResponse)` works for me.  Intellisense was suggesting system.net.httpresponse, but using .Web works

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current uses the Ambient Context design pattern, so you should be able to access the Response object from just about anywhere in your code. It is very useful.

For those wondering, the Ambient Context pattern is very cool, and is detailed here:

http://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/